# Generalized Itô's formula for random mappings

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

If $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a (nice) semimartingale and $F: [0,\infty) \times \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ is a sufficiently regular mapping, then Itô's formula allows us to calculate the stochastic differential of $F(t,X_t)$.

I'm interested in the more general case that the function $F$ itself is random, i.e. $$F: \Omega \times [0,\infty) \times \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}, (\omega,t,x) \mapsto F(\omega,t,x),$$ and $F$ has a stochastic differential of the form $$d_t F(t,x) = A(t,x) \, dt+ C(t,x) \, dW_t + \int g(t,x,y) \, N(dt,dy) + \int h(t,x,y) \tilde{N}(dt,dy) \tag{1}$$ where $(W_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a Brownian motion, $N$ a Poisson measure and $\tilde{N}$ the compensated Poisson measure.

> I'm looking for a reference where the stochastic differential $d F(t,X_t)$ is calculated (rigorously!) for random mappings $F$ of the form $(1)$.

I'm aware of the following publications:

- [Kunita](https://eudml.org/doc/113315) considers the Brownian framework, i.e. $g=h=0$.
- There is a recent [publication](https://link.springer.com/article/10.3103/S1055134416010028) by Karachanskaya covering the SDEs of the form (1) with $h=0$.

---

(Just as a side remark: I believe that the proof of the result is not too complicated (in fact, very similar to the proof of Itô's formula), but quite lengthy, and therefore I would prefer to have a nice reference rather than proving the result on my own.)